# Actualizar registro en mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

tengo un problema con una función de python. Debe actualizar la información de un registro en la base de datos mysql, el problema es que cuando lo ejecuto, me arroja un error en la sintaxis:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index= 8' at
> line 1

dejo aquí el código:

```
def modificar_registro():
     
    conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
    cursor1=conn.cursor()   
    comando='''UPDATE ticket SET Numero_guia = %s, Peso_guia = %s, Producto = %s, Transporte= %s, Proveedor = %s, Despacho = %s, Observaciones = %s WHERE index= %s ''' 
    entradas=  (entry_numeroguia.get(), entry_pesoguia.get(), entrada_producto.get(), entrada_transporte.get(), entrada_prov_cli.get(), entrada_destino.get(), entrada_observaciones.get(), indice)
    cursor1.execute(comando, entradas)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

agradezco a cualquiera que me pueda decir que hice mal, gracias.

Comment: Puede ser que el espacio que esta al final haya que quitarlo? Por que con una mirada no noto nada extraño...

Comment: Si hermano, no sé que pasa, estoy tentado a subir el código a stackoverflow en ingles, a ver si hay suerte allí

Comment: Tiene sentido. Sinceramente, yo pregunto en SO en inglès, por que hay más gente allí. Sin embargo, ten cuidado, pues si alguien (aqui o allá) se da cuenta de que resultó ser un error de sintaxis, probablemente decidan cerrarte la pregunta. Suerte!

Comment: Espera, hice pruebas online y tengo una hipotesis. En un rato te doy una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Parece que la palabra `index` está reservada. La vi en dos paginas de palabras reservadas como una palabra reservada. Esta es una de ellas: [https://doc.ispirer.com/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-205.html#:~:text=IN-,INDEX,-INFILE](https://doc.ispirer.com/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-205.html#:%7E:text=IN-,INDEX,-INFILE)

La solución, es indicar explicitamente a mysql que se trata de un identificador (no se bien que es, pero suele representar nombres de columnas, tablas y esquemas) usando backticks.

```
UPDATE ticket SET Numero_guia = 1 WHERE `index`= 0
```

O, cambiando el nombre de la columna:

```
UPDATE ticket SET Numero_guia = 1 WHERE indice= 0
```

Si haces esto, no olvides cambiar el nombre de la columna al nuevo en todos los lugares en el que usas el nombre anterior.

Comment: Noté esto por que la pagina que usé para probar los querys me resaltó la palabra con un color.

Comment: Esa es la cuestión, idex no es el nombre de ninguna variable, lo uso para referirme al índice del registro en la base de datos, lo que se llama "primary key". En otras versiones, usé "oid" en lugar de index, pero la consola arrojó: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'oid' in 'where clause' a pesar de que esa es la palabra usada en varios tutoriales.

Comment: Este es el comando: ` comando='''UPDATE ticket SET Numero_guia = %s, Peso_guia = %s, Producto = %s, Transporte= %s, Proveedor = %s, Despacho = %s, Observaciones = %s WHERE oid= %s'''   `

Comment: Querés obtener el número de registro? Las bases de datos no tienen eso (a lo sumo una primary key incremental que no decrece cuando borras un registro). Lo que acabo de mencionar entre parentesis en sqlite3 es una columna llamada rowid, que se crea automaticamente por default. No se si MySql tenga algo similar o no. Voy a ver el tema. Mientras tanto, te recomiendo aclarar eso en la pregunta.

Comment: Hola @DanteS., disculpa que hubiera tardado tanto. Si, lo que busco obtener es la llave primaria (creo pero no estoy seguro, que en mysql se llama identificador de objeto "oid") el punto es identificar el registro específico para poder borrarlo o modificarlo